# How do you wrap a uibModal controller in brackets to protect it from minifying

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a modal  function that is having a problem when I minify. It's because the controller isn't wrapped in brackets.

With a regular controller, I would use " .controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope){});

But with my modal, it just calls a straight function:

```
        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            animation: true,
            backdrop: 'static',
            keyboard: false,
            templateUrl: 'questionsModal.html',
            controller: function($scope, $uibModalInstance, SweetAlert) {
```

I tried the following:

```
            var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                animation: true,
                backdrop: 'static',
                keyboard: false,
                templateUrl: 'questionsModal.html',
                controller: ('', [ '$scope', function($scope) {}])
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
 var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                animation: true,
                backdrop: 'static',
                keyboard: false,
                templateUrl: 'questionsModal.html',
                controller: ['$scope', '$uibModalInstance', 'SweetAlert', function($scope, $uibModalInstance, SweetAlert) {
                 }]
```

Comment: I am glad I helped